# Can't get a session id

Tags: php

I must have something funky with my new server setup. (Cent OS)  These two simple lines of code give me a blank session id.  Shouldn't a session id be automatically generated and assigned?

```
session_start();
echo "Your session_id=".session_id()."<br/>";
```

Thanks.

Comment: I changed the code a little just to make sure PHP was saving session variables.  And it is saving them fine.  If I add: ----- 
$_SESSION['X'] = 22;
echo "SESSION['X']=".$_SESSION['X']."<br/>";   ----- Then it shows the value of $_SESSION['X'] just fine.  But session_id() is still blank?

Comment: do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: After a few more tests, I think that PHP is not remembering session variable from page to page.  I can set it and then read it later on that same page.  But otherwise they aren't working.  I'm thinking somewhere in my PHP.INI configuration something needs changing?

Comment: chk if session_start() returns true or false, did u have cookies on?